# Conversor de decimal para binário em C

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um código em C para um trabalho de faculdade com o objetivo de converter um número decimal para binário. Porém quando o programa executa, ele sempre imprime 00000000, não importando qual número eu coloque. Alguém saberia dizer qual é o erro? Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int num;
    int bin[7];
    int aux;

    printf("Digite o número (base decimal) para ser convertido: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (aux = 7; aux >= 0; aux--) {
        if (num % 2 == 0) {
            bin[aux] = 0;
            num = num / 2;
        }
        else {
            bin[aux] = 1;
            num = num / 2;
        }
    }

    for (aux = 0; aux <= 7; aux++) {
        printf("%d", bin[aux]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qual seria a lógica que você utilizou na linha `num = (num / 2) - 0.5;`? Esta subtração de 0.5 não faz muito sentido (lembrando que a variável é do tipo `int`, portanto, quando um valor ímpar é dividido por dois, o resultado é arredondado para baixo; por exemplo, 5/2 = 2).

Comment: Precisa funcionar para números negativos?

Comment: Verdade, consertei essa parte, mas o problema continua. Não precisa pra números negativos

Comment: https://repl.it/HUEA/0 aqui funcionou perfeitamente. Como está testando?

Comment: Fiz no Dev-C++... provavelmente é problema do compilador então

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286742/64969

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como obter a representação de um número inteiro positivo em binário, usando recursão?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/267758/como-obter-a-representa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-um-n%c3%bamero-inteiro-positivo-em-bin%c3%a1rio-usando-recu)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Não é duplicata por causa da recursão. O caso aqui é mais fechar como um problema que não pode ser reproduzido. Testei o código aqui e funcionou. O Woss há mais de um ano atrás também testou e também funcionou.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado É mais próximo da pergunta que você relacionou em abril deste ano.

Answer (score 1):

Não consegui reproduzir o erro reportado, mas tem um erro na declaração do array "bin", que pela sua lógica precisa ter 8 elementos. Fora isso, não parece ter nada errado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int num;
   int bin[8]; // <---------------
   int aux;

   printf("Digite o número (base decimal) para ser convertido: ");
   scanf("%d", &num);

   for (aux = 7; aux >= 0; aux--)
   {
      if (num % 2 == 0)
         bin[aux] = 0;
      else
         bin[aux] = 1;
      num = num / 2;
   }

   for (aux = 0; aux < 8; aux++)
       printf("%d", bin[aux]);

   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```