# Como imprimir a representação binária de um caracter?

Tags: c, string

Eu estou precisando obter a representação binária dos caráteres de uma *string*.

Eu consigo fazer a representação hexadecimal com o próprio `printf` usando **`%x`**.

Algo como:

```
void imprime_hex(char *input) {
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
    printf("%x\n", input[i]);
  }
}
```

<sup>[**Veja executando no Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/NanoFlamboyantAnalysts)</sup>

Existe algo parecido para imprimir a representação binária? Ou alguma função que possa me auxiliar a obter tal resultado?

Btw, eu imagino que isso vá variar conforme codificação, etc. Não é necessário se preocupar com isso, a ideia é usar apenas os caracteres "comuns": A-Z, a-z, 0-9.

Comment: **Nota:** No SOen tem um exemplo com `itoa`, mas devo lhe adiantar que isto não é standard, então talvez não funcione em alguns compiladores, acaso alguém apareça com uma resposta sobre isto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem nada pronto.

De fato para fazer algo *production ready* precisa tratar muita coisa, analisar o *endianess*, etc. Algo ingênuo não universal seria isto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void BinFormat(char character, char *text) {
    text[8] = '\0';
    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) text[i] = ((character >> i) & 1) + '0';
}

int main(void) {
    char *text = malloc(9);
    BinFormat('A', text);
    printf("%s\n", text);
    BinFormat('B', text);
    printf("%s\n", text);
    BinFormat('C', text);
    printf("%s\n", text);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/gEbbYg). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/rxatxaua-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/CharToBinary.c).

A estratégia de como alocar memória pode variar. Não gosto muito de alocar no *heap*, mas é a mais simples e correta.

Como C tem a incrível deficiência de não poder retornar um *array*, poderia retornar uma `struct` com 8 ou 9 `chars`, mas depois exigiria um *cast* para transformar em uma *string* real.

Dependendo do caso poderia ter todos os caracteres imprimíveis (95) em uma tabela estática, ocuparia 855 bytes, mas teria a vantagem de ser muito rápida. Mas algo mais universal exigira mais memória.

Não tem solução boa.

Assim é uma solução mais legível?

```
int divisor = (int)pow(2, i); //base 2 elevado à posição que está para achar o divisor
printf("[%d, ", divisor);
int cabe = character / divisor; //acha quantas unidades cabem no divisor
printf("%d, ", cabe);
int impar = (cabe % 2 != 0); //o que cabe é impar?
printf("%d] ", impar);
text[i] = impar + 48; //avança na tabela ASCII 48 posições para chegar em '0' ou '1'
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3Cx3Qv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kdvhpnay-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/CharToBinarySimplied.c).

Vamos agora deixar mais C:

```
int divisor = i; //base 2 elevado à posição que está para achar o divisor
printf("[%d, ", divisor);
int cabe = character >> i; //acha quantas unidades cabem no divisor
printf("%d, ", cabe);
int impar = cabe & 1; //o que cabe é impar?
printf("%d] ", impar);
text[i] = impar + '0'; //avança na tabela ASCII até o '0' ou '1' se for 0 ou 1
```

Comment: Tem como explicar o bloco dentro do `for`?

Comment: @LINQ expliquei, e tinha um erro, comecei fazendo de um jeito, depois mudei e como testei um exemplo que engana no *endianess* não percebi, agora está correto.